# If I click logout button once the session doesn’t expire instead only after clicking the logout several times it is getting expired

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, session-cookies

I am facing some issues while logging out from the URL. If I click logout button once the session doesn’t expire  instead only after clicking the logout several times it is getting expired

Have invalidated the session still the page is not getting logging out.

```
<%
        String appName = request.getParameter("_appName");
        System.out.println("appName is "+appName);
        String cookieAppName = null;
        String logOut = null;
        String applicationURL = null;
        String appNameContext = "";
        try {            

            HashMap cookieMap = new HashMap();
            cookieMap.put("IRSESSIONID", "IRSESSIONID");
            cookieMap.put("TraSESSIONID", "TraSESSIONID");
            cookieMap.put("appname", "appname");
            Person person = PersonUtil.getPersonFromSession(request);
            if(person.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase("EMP") || person.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase("EMP_New")){
            logOut = PropertyConfig.getProperty("new.url");
            }else{
            logOut = PropertyConfig.getProperty("old.url");
            }
            applicationURL = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName();    
            log.debug("Application URL  ---- " + applicationURL); 



            logOut = logOut + URLEncoder.encode(applicationURL,Constants.URL_ENC); 
           //session terminate
            request.getSession().invalidate(); 

            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

            if(cookies != null) {
                for(int i=0;i < cookies.length; i++){

                    System.out.println(cookies[i].getName() + " --> " + cookies[i].getValue() + " :: " + cookies[i].getMaxAge());

                    String currCookie = cookies[i].getName();

                    System.out.println(cookies[i].getName() + " --> " + cookies[i].getValue() + " : " + cookies[i].getMaxAge());



                log.debug("Redirecting to ---- " + logOut);   
              //  System.out.println("Redirecting to ---- " + logOut);
                %>

                <%
                response.sendRedirect(logOut);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("An error occured while killing the weblogic sesion and deleting the cookies", e);
            response.sendRedirect(logOut);
        }%>
```

From Servlet

```
function confirmLogoff()
{

    try {
        var message = 'Do you want to proceed with logout?';
        var confirmed = confirm(message);
        if(confirmed == true){
            closeWindow();
            window.location = ""/logut/jsp/Signoff.jsp";
        }
    } catch (e) {

    }
```

}

The session should expire after clicking logout button instead the session is still persistent

Comment: Add the code defining the button (i.e. how the above code is invoked).

Comment: @JozefChocholacek This is in JSP page ,  which called during the window.location = ""/logut/jsp/Signoff.jsp"; in Login Page